# Rails: Is it possible to write view helpers with HAML syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, haml, view-helpers

During refactoring it would be quite handy just to copy part of HAML template and paste it to helper's code. Currently in such cases 1) I have to rewrite that part of view from scratch 2) I have to use that verbose syntax like content_tag or haml_tag.

I know that it's possible to define partials with HAML systax that will serve as helper. Though 1) as for me it's inconvinient to create a separate file for each small tiny function 2) invocation syntax for partial is quite verbose.

Ideally i'd like my *_helper class to look like this:

```
- def some_helper(*its_args)
  .some_class
    = some_ruby_expression
  %some_tag#some_id
    - another_expression do
      etc
```

or at least like this:

```
define_haml_helper :some_helper, [:arg1, :arg2], %{
  .some_class
    = some_ruby_expression
  %some_tag#some_id
    - another_expression do
      etc
}
```

Is there a plugin that solves my issue?

Alternatively, maybe you can describe how do you refactor HAML snippets to reusable elements (helpers/functions/partials/builders/etc)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [reference](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html):

```
def render_haml(code)
    engine = Haml::Engine.new(code)
    engine.render
end
```

This initiates a new Haml engine and renders it.

Comment: It would be nice to have the functionality wrapped with pritty-looking syntax for engine caching. I just wonder maybe there exists a gem for that matter.

Comment: @Alexy I'm bored anyway so I'll write that gem. Soon. I can't think of such a gem that already exists right now but it's not hard to implement.

Comment: is it worth caching this? so @haml_engine ||= etc... ?

Comment: @PeterEhrlich I have a helper method called `hamlize` which consists only of `Haml::Engine.new( yield ).render if block_given?` This seems to do what you're thinking of: `hamlize{ "%div.some-class" + some_method_that_returns_valid_haml( arg1, arg2 ) }` Though I would be interested in the answer to @Simon's comment too -- not sure if I should cache the Engine? Also still working on getting other helper methods into the Engine's context...

Comment: @Simon that will break if you want to render different templates.

Answer (score 4):

If all you are after is a method for small reusable snippets, how about partials with local variables? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Answer (score 3):

Haml now has a `capture_haml` method that you can use to accomplish this.

```
  def some_helper
    capture_haml do
      .some_class
        = yield
      #some-code-after
    end
  end

some_helper do
  %h1 Hello World
end
=> <div class="some_class">
     <h1>Hello World</h1>
   </div>
   <div id="some-code-after"></div>
```

Here is a link with more info on `capture_haml`:
http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#capture_haml-instance_method

Comment: I think you misunderstood the meaning of the function. The snippet you gave cannot work - you cannot put HAML right in the middle of Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I used heredoc for such purposes:

```
  def view_helper
    Haml::Engine.new(<<~HAML).render
      .example
        #id ID
        .desc Description
    HAML
  end
```

This way has a lot of issues with a scope of variables, so, as mentioned above, the much more correct way is to use partials for this.

**UPD1:** here is a solution on how to solve issues with scope:

```
  def view_helper
    Haml::Engine.new(<<~HAML).render(self)
      .form
        = form_tag root_path do
          = submit_tag :submit
    HAML
  end
```

**UPD2:** even better solution(founded on the internet):

```
def render_haml(haml, locals = {})
  Haml::Engine.new(haml.strip_heredoc, format: :html5).render(self, locals)
end

def greeting
  render_haml <<-HAML
    .greeting
      Welcome to
      %span.greeting--location
        = Rails.env
  HAML
end
```