# How to call helper in Haml file

Tags: ruby, haml

How do I call a method in a helper from a Haml file?

In sample.haml, I need to call the `show_message` method depending on some condition. Then I moved the method to the helper, but the returned value from the method is treated as just a string, not a Haml element.

This is sample.haml:

```
- flash.each do |msg|
  - if msg.is_a?(Array)
    - msg.each do |m|
      = show_message(m)
  - if msg.is_a?(String)
    = show_message(msg)
```

This is helper.rb:

```
  def show_message(msg)
    haml = <<-HAML
    %div{class: some_class}
      = content_tag :div, #{msg}, id: "id"
    HAML
  end
```

If I write the same HTML element in `show_message` in sample.html directly, it works properly. How can I solve this?

Comment: [Rails: Is it possible to write view helpers with HAML syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5245939/23915)

Answer (score 0):

Your helper method needs to construct the full HTML via methods. Since it's not actually part of the HAML, you cannot rely on syntax like `%div{class: some_class}`. Something like this:

```
def show_message(msg)
  content_tag(:div, class: 'some_class') do
    content_tag(:div, msg, id: "id")
  end
end
```

See the [`content_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag)  documentation for more usage examples.